# Basis in Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Prove that the set of functions

$C$ = { $f_{0}(x)= \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}$, $f_{n}(x)= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cdot \cos(nx), n \in \Bbb N$ }

is an orthonormal basis in $L^{2}(0, \pi)$.

Hint: Use the facts that the set of continuous functions on compact interval are dense in $L^2$ and every
polynomial on compact interval is dense in the set of continuous functions (Stone-Weierstrass theorem).
You need to show that $\overline{Sp(C)}$ =$L^2(0, \pi)$.

I have a key but I do not understand this question, especially third hint. I feel sorry. If you have any clear solution for the question, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not understand the question, I do not think that an answer will help you. You should first try to understand the question. In the last hint, $Sp(C)$ is the linear hull (span) of $C$ and the line denotes the closure.